# Laravel 6 - CSRF token mismatch en Docker

Tags: docker, laravel-6, docker-compose

Tengo básicamente un problema con el token en una app de L6.

Actualmente el sitio en desarrollo funciona bien en mi máquina. Todos los formularios funcionan bien, puedo iniciar/cerrar sesión y así.

Ahora moví el sitio a una máquina de desarrollo donde se maneja Docker. El sitio abre, se conecta a la base de datos y muestra el formulario para iniciar sesión. El problema está en que cada que se trata de iniciar sesión, al hacer clic en el botón, inmediatamente genera un error 419, donde el error es ***CSRF token mismatch.***. El campo oculto donde está el token lo genero dentro del formulario con **@csrf** y el valor coincide con el del atributo meta de la página.

Ya borré todo lo que concierne a caché, pero el problema persiste. A alguien le ha ocurrido algo similar y ha podido solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ni idea del por qué, pero, repitiendo una vez más el cambio del valor de la variable *SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE* de false a true y luego a false de nuevo y corriendo ene veces el comando artisan para limpiar caché de rutas, vistas, configuraciones y caché/sesiones finalmente funcionó.